# nginx serves only React HTML code in JS static build files after adding try_files directive

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I am building an React app image using this multi-stage build Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as build

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./

RUN npm config set @bit:registry https://node.bit.dev
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

COPY . ./

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

and then I'm running it in a container on `port 3000`.

Besides this I'm also running an `nginx` container with the next configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name _;
    server_tokens off;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}

server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:3000;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Now when I'm trying to access the domain the redirection seems to be working fine, but nginx seem to not serve the files correctly. In the JS static main chunk file I get only html code:

[image]

I think this must be an issue with the `try_files` directive because if I'm commenting that line out, I can see the first page. Also, if I'm not using nginx and open port 3000 in the firewall, the first page is again visible.

Can someone please lead me in the right direction with this configuration?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I wrote the `try_files` directive for redirecting everything to my `index.html` so that React can handle the routing in the nginx container running on my server and not the one built inside my React image with multi-stage build. Once I wrote the directive in the configuration file inside my React container and removed it from nginx, everything started working just fine.